# How to add picture to every panel?

Tags: panels

I am using the panels module and the mini panels modules.

I have mini panel with two section (left and right).
For my design, I want to add a picture on the left side of each section. These pictures are not supposed to come from any node or content, they are just pictures for design purpose only.

How can I do that?
If you suggest CSS, I will be happy to understand how?

I am a newbie, and building my first Drupal site, so I will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All your panels have a common class. Probably .panels. You need to see if your left panels also have a common class, probably .panel-left or something. You can use your browsers element-inspector to see this. It will show you something like this (simplified example) if you select your node that has panels:

```
<div class="panels">
  <div class="panel-left">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives you a clue where to set your background in CSS.

```
.panels .panel-left {
  background:url('path/image');
}
```

You need to find classes that the elements you want to style have in common, but are unique enough so that you style only those.

Comment: Thanks a lot!I did that, and it's working nicely.
But, I am using responsive theme, and when I am re-sizing the window, the text & info of the panels are going on top of the picture, something I want to avoid. I don't want the text covering the picture. how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: set margins to the field inside the panel.